# Is it undefined behavior to cast from a struct with a flexible array member to an otherwise identical one without?

Tags: c, struct, c99

I want to have a variably sized struct, but I want to embed an instance of the struct with a certain size into another struct. Here's the idea:

```c
struct grid {
    size_t width, height;
    int items[ /* width * height */ ];
};

struct grid_1x1 {
    size_t width, height;
    int items[1];
};

struct grid_holder {
    struct grid_1x1 a, b;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct grid_holder h = {
        .a = { .width = 1, .height = 1, .items = { 0 } },
        .b = { .width = 1, .height = 1, .items = { 0 } },
    };
    struct grid *a = (struct grid *)&h.a, *b = (struct grid *)&h.b;
}
```

If all my code assumes that the `items` member of `struct grid` has `width * height` elements, is it alright to cast `a` and `b` as I have above?

In other words, does a flexible array member with one element always have the same offset and size as a fixed-size array member with one element, given that the structs are otherwise identical? I'd like an answer based on the C99 standard. If the offsets might differ, is there another way to achieve my goal stated at the beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

The rule in C 2018 6.5 7 or C 1999 6.5 7 about which types may be used to access an object is not just about how the objects are laid out and represented. So the sentence in the question “In other words, does a flexible array member with one element always have the same offset and size as a fixed-size array member with one element, given that the structs are otherwise identical?” is incorrect. Having the same offset and size, even having identical structure definitions, does not make structures compatible for aliasing.

Different structures are different types deliberately. Consider these two types:

```
typedef struct { double real, imaginary; } Complex;
typedef struct { double x, y; } Coordinates;
```

These structures have identical definitions (except for the member names, but the following holds even if their names were identical), but they are different and incompatible types according to the C standard. This means that in a routine such as:

```
double foo(Complex *a, Coordinates *b)
{
    a->real = 3; a->imaginary = 4;
    b->x = 5; b->y = 6;
    return sqrt(a->real*a->real + a->imaginary*a->imaginary);
}
```

the compiler is permitted to optimize the last statement to `return 5;` on the basis that `b->x = 5; b->y = 6;` cannot have changed `a` because `a` and `b` cannot be pointing to the same object, or, if they are, the behavior of `b->x = 5; b->y = 6;` is not defined.

So the C rules about aliasing are about compatible types plus various exceptions for particular cases. They are not primarily about how structures are laid out.

In contrast to the above example with different-but-identically-defined structures, when we have multiple pointers to the same structure type, the compiler cannot assume that `a` and `b` are not aliases (different names) for the same object. In:

```
double foo(Complex *a, Complex *b)
{
    a->real = 3; a->imaginary = 4;
    b->real = 5; b->imaginary = 6;
    return sqrt(a->real*a->real + a->imaginary*a->imaginary);
}
```

the compiler cannot assume the return value is 5 because `a` and `b` may point to the same object, in which case `b->real = 5; b->imaginary = 6;` changes the contents of `a`.

Comment: Any question of what the Standard means would revolve around the question of what it means for an object's stored value to be accessed "by" an lvalue expression.  If one interprets N1570 6.5p7 literally, it would require programmers to jump through hoops to do much of anything, since neither an assignment expression nor a declaration containing an initializer is an lvalue expression.

Comment: @supercat: An assignment expression has an lvalue expression as its left operand, and it is entirely clear that the assignment accesses the object referred to by that expression. (“Access” means either read or write.) An initialization is not problematic since the effective type of a declared object is its declared type, so an initialization cannot be accessing the object being defined with anything other than its effective type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: If an non-VLA automatic-object declaration with an initializer, the automatic object comes into existence when code enters its scope, but the initialization expression isn't evaluated until shortly after that, implying that the object is modified during its lifetime.  Obviously the Standard isn't intended to forbid that usage, but since only a deliberately obtuse compiler would care about whether such the Standard mandated that such declarations be processed meaningfully, there was no need for the authors of the Standard to worry about whether it did.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Otherwise, how about `someStruct.arrayMember[index] = 23;`?  In the evaluation of that expression, the only use of `someStruct.arrayMember` is to produce a pointer value.

Comment: @supercat: Whether or when initialization accesses an object makes no difference because, as I explained previously, the types match, and therefore no violation of 6.5 7 is possible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The way N1570 6.5p7 is worded, objects may only have their stored values accessed "only by lvalue expressions".  It doesn't say "lvalue expressions of only the following types", but rather "only by lvalues expressions of the following types".

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate issues you need to worry about:

1. The Standard allows implementations to place arbitrary amounts of padding between structure members, provided only that the total amount of padding before any structure member is affected only by the types of that member and preceding members.  For this purpose, arrays of different sizes are considered different types.  At least in theory, some implementations targeting weird architectures might vary the padding before an array based upon its size.  For example, on a platform where addresses identify 32-bit words but there are instructions to read and write 8-bit chunks within them, an implementation given `struct x1 { long l; char a,b[4], c;};` could decide to pad the start of `b` so the whole thing fits in a single word, even if that same implementation given `struct x1 { long l; char a,b[5], c;};` would not add such padding (since parts of `b` would be split between two words regardless).  I'm unaware of any implementations that actually do such things, but the Committee would likely expected that the only time such laxity would matter would be if compilers were being developed and used on such platforms, and in that case people working with such platforms would be better able than the Committee to judge the pros and cons of different padding approaches.
2. Although the Common Initial Sequence rule was by all indications intended to allow a pointer to one structure type to be used to inspect any part of a Common Initial Sequence of other structure types (such ability is documented in the 1974 C Reference Guide, and after unions were added to the language, compilers would have had to go out of their way to support such usage with unions without also supporting it with structure pointers), the authors of clang and gcc regard as broken any code that would rely upon such treatment, and actively refuse to support such code except by use of the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag.

I'd regard the first issue as purely theoretical, but the second issue means that any code which would attempt to use pointer to access multiple separately-declared structure types would need to use the `-fno-strict-aliasing` option when building with gcc or clang.  That shouldn't be a problem, but the second issue means that anyone whose code might be used with clang or gcc would need to ensure that anyone using those compilers is aware of the need for the `-fno-strict-aliasing` (i.e. "don't be obtuse") flag.  So far as I can tell, compilers that are designed for paying customers support the constructs usefully even when using `-fstrict-aliasing` because supporting them is useful and not difficult, but the maintainers of gcc and clang are ideologically opposed to such support.

Comment: The common initial sequence rule applies only to structures in the same union.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: In the language described by the 1974 C Reference Guide, it applied to structures accessed via pointers, and defining how things worked with unions, combined with saying that objects in unions had the same address, meant that the rule would remain useful with pointers (as it had been in 1974 C) unless compilers went out of their way to prevent it from being so.